# If values in two columns satisfy two different conditions, store corresponding value of third column into a list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-manipulation

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
col1   col2    col3    y
1      2       2       10
0      1       0       15
2      2       1       17
1      2       1       9
2      0       0       8
0      1       2       21
```

I want to store the value in `y` in a list if `col1` and `col2` meet two separate conditions.

In this example my conditions are if if the value in `col1` == 0 and the value in `col2` == 1, then store the value of `y` in the list.

`col3` is completely ignored. I just added it in here because my actual dataframe has many columns that I am not interested in.

So, in this example, the result would be a list of length 2 with the values "15" and "21" inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)


data <-
  data.frame(
    col1 = c(1,0,2,0),
    col2 = c(2,1,2,1),
    y = c(10,15,17,21)
  )

data %>% 
  filter(col1 == 0 & col2 == 1) %>% 
  pull(y) %>% 
  as.list()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from yours without using dplyr. You can use the [subset](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/subset) function.

```
# Create a sample data frame
df = data.frame(col1 = c(1,0,2,1,2,0),
                col2 = c(2,1,2,2,0,1),
                col3 = c(2,0,1,1,0,2),
                y = c(10,15,17,9,8,21))

# Use the subset() function to extract rows where col1 == 0 and col2 == 1
filtered_df = subset(df, col1 == 0 & col2 == 1)

# Extract the values of column "y" from the filtered data frame
y_values = filtered_df$y

# Print the y_values
print(y_values)
```

You can also use the `[` operator

```
# Use the [ operator to extract rows where col1 == 0 and col2 == 1
filtered_df = df[df$col1 == 0 & df$col2 == 1,]
```

Comment: `subset()` also has the option of choosing the column(s) directly - `subset(df, col1 == 0 & col2 == 1, select=y)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use select(y) + as.list(). The pull method will give you a list for each value of y. If you want a single list that has all the values, you can use select.

```
data <-
        data.frame(
            col1 = c(1,0,2,0),
            col2 = c(2,1,2,1),
            y = c(10,15,17,21)
        )

data %>% 
    filter(col1 == 0 & col2 == 1) %>% 
    select(y)%>% as.list()
```